# VBA InStr function limited match workaround in loop

Tags: vba, loops, dynamic, match

I am trying to figure out how to workaround a wildcard solution for the InStr function in a dynamic setup.

Currently i am using the below code (based on the example in below picture) to loop through the data:

```
Sub Test()
 Dim Rng_Target As Range
 Dim Rng_Data As Range
 Dim RCntr_Target As Long
 Dim RCntr_Data As Long
 Dim Str_Tgt As String

    Set Rng_Target = Range("E2:E3")
    Set Rng_Data = Range("A2:C15")

    For RCntr_Target = 0 To Rng_Target.Rows.Count

        Str_Tgt = Rng_Target(RCntr_Target) & "High" & Rng_Target(RCntr_Target) & "Major"

        For RCntr_Data = 0 To Rng_Data.Rows.Count

            If InStr(1, Str_Tgt, Rng_Data(RCntr_Target, 1) & Rng_Data(RCntr_Target, 2)) > 0 Then

                If Rng_Data(RCntr_Target, 3) < 0.9 Then

                    ' Do something

                End If

            End If

        Next RCntr_Data

    Next RCntr_Target

End Sub
```

This setup works for 9 out of 10 of my setups, but it cannot handle ***pre-target tags*** such as "**Green_**".

**See below image of simplified example**. Is there a way i can skip the first X number (needs to be dynamic) of characters in the matching string?

[image: Example1]

---

There are a few thing you need to have in mind

1. There are +5.000 rows with many different targets so it needs to be dynamic.
2. The data should be included if column A partly match the target, and that column B is either High or Major. the outcome is illustrated in **Target1** box and **Target2** box.
3. There are dozens of ***pre-target tags*** e.g. "**Green_**"  and i do not keep a register on them.
4. There are multiple code constructions as the one above, and it would be very problematic if i need to split up the InStr function or mix in more if functions.

e.g.:

```
If InStr(1, Rng_Target(RCntr_Target), Rng_Data(RCntr_Target, 1)) > 0 Then

    If InStr(1, "HighMajor", Rng_Data(RCntr_Target, 2)) > 0 Then

        If Rng_Data(RCntr_Target, 3) < 0.9 Then

            ' Do something

        End If

    End If

End If
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the tags you are trying to parse? If they all follow similar naming rules it shouldnt be too difficult. Before we can come up with a solution though, we need to know what the strings look like as they come in. Also, your picture isnt showing.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Please see attached picture in OP. Let me know if more detailed example is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having a hard time understanding what your code is trying to accomplish, but I get the gist of the problem you are having. I tried to come up with a code example that (hopefully) accomplishes your task, but also makes your code cleaner. See below:

First, we create a custom function for returning a clean product name:

```
Private Function GetProductName(ByVal InputProductName As String) As String
    Dim ProductName As String

    If InStr(1, InputProductName, "_") > 0 Then
        ProductName = Split(InputProductName, "_")(1)
    Else
        ProductName = InputProductName
    End If

    GetProductName = ProductName
End Function
```

What this does is takes an input string, and checks for an underscore "_". If there is an underscore, it returns the second part of the input string. If there isn't one, it just returns the string itself.

Then we have the meat of the routine:

```
    Sub FilterProducts()
        Dim InputData As Variant

        ' Point this to the range where you input data is. If only your input data is on the sheet then use the UsedRange version (for simplicity).
        ' InputData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ProductInformation").UsedRange.Value
        InputData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ProductInformation").Range("A1:C15").Value

        ' To keep this dynamic I use a Scripting.Dictionary trick to dynamically find the headers I am interested in.
        Dim HeaderIndices As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set HeaderIndices = New Scripting.Dictionary

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(InputData, 2) To UBound(InputData, 2)
            ' Basically we are looping from the lowest column, to the highest column.
            ' We then check if that header exists within the dictionary, and if it doesn't
            ' we add the header as a key, with the index as the item.
            If Not HeaderIndices.Exists(InputData(LBound(InputData, 1), i)) Then
                HeaderIndices.Add InputData(LBound(InputData, 1), i), i
            End If
        Next

        ' Now we will loop row-wise through the data to find the data we are interested in.
        Dim ProductName As String
        For i = LBound(InputData, 1) + 1 To UBound(InputData, 1)
            ' Our row index is i (since we are looping from top to bottom)
            ' Our column index is retrieved from the dictionary under the key of
            ' "Fruit". You would want to change this to match the actual column name
            ' in your input data.
            ProductName = GetProductName(InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Fruit")))

            If InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Probability")) = "High" Or _
            InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Probability")) = "Major" Then
                If InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Value")) < 0.9 Then
                    ' Do Something
                    ' This is where you will want to figure out your process for creating the output.
                    ' I would personally suggest learning about arrays.
                    Debug.Print "Product Name: " & ProductName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                                "Probability: " & InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Probability")) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                                "Value : " & InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Value"))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

I tried to add comments to this to make it as clear as possible. Some of this can be removed if you want to use static indices (however I do suggest learning the more dynamic approach). This will take an input range, and loop through the data looking for "Fruit" "Probability" and "Value". It then prints out matching products to the console (change this portion to meet your needs of course).

Finally, in order to use Scripting.Dictionaries you need either Late or Early binding. I prefer Early binding (using a reference) so here is the code I use for that purpose.

```
' You can put this in your Workbook.Open routine if you are sharing the workbook, or you can run it as a command from the immediate window.

AddReferencebyGUID "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"

' If you do use the Workbook.Open Event, use this code:
If CheckForAccess Then
    RemoveBrokenReferences
    AddReferencebyGUID "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"
End If

Private Sub RemoveBrokenReferences()
    ' Reference is a Variant here since it requires an external reference.
    ' It isnt possible to ensure that the external reference is checked when this process runs.
    Dim Reference As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Reference = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)
        If Reference.IsBroken Then
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove Reference
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function CheckForAccess() As Boolean
    ' Checks to ensure access to the Object Model is set
    Dim VBP As Variant
    If Val(Application.Version) >= 10 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set VBP = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please pay attention to this message." _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Your security settings do not allow this procedure to run." _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "To change your security setting:" _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " 1. Select File - Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Settings - Macro Settings." & vbCrLf _
                 & " 2. Place a checkmark next to 'Trust access to the VBA project object model.'" _
                 & vbCrLf & "Once you have completed this process, please save and reopen the workbook." _
                 & vbCrLf & "Please reach out for assistance with this process.", _
                   vbCritical
            CheckForAccess = False
            Err.Clear
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    CheckForAccess = True
End Function
```

The code for the references is strictly for binding (which may be beyond what you have learned so far). You can copy and paste that code and you shouldnt have any issues. I would recommend spending more time on learning how the main routine is working, so you can replicate the process in the future.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you Brandon. I will check it out. In regards to "'do something" i am using arrays. The HeaderIndices is a nice touch i haven't used before - great way for outsiders to "see/understand" what you are doing. One thing, the reason why i am creating a string with both High and Major is to avoid using `Or` in my code as i find it rather slow, especially if you are looping through many arrays using several `If/Case` constrains:             `If InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Probability")) = "High" Or _
            InputData(i, HeaderIndices("Probability")) = "Major"`

Comment: I would be genuinely surprised if the concatenation and then into method is more efficient than an Or conditional. I have used many of these before and haven't noticed an impact.